# bootstraps select menu into a dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu

> I have a select option in a form, but i need it to be bootstrap
>   select button,I tried but failed with it,I think plugings are wrong or
>   something.

```
           <select name="city">
                <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
                <option value="Brisbane">Brisbaneo</option>
                <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
                <option value="Canberra">Canberra</option>
                <option value="Darwin">Darwin</option>
                <option value="Perth">Perth</option>
           </select>
            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" /></li>
        </ul>

    </form>
```

> This is my try :-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Select City
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sydney</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Brisbane</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Melbourne</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Canberra</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Darwin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Perth</a></li>

    </ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>
```

> php for this list

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 switch($_POST['city']) {
  case 'gampaha': $to = 'to1@gmail.com'; break;
  case 'colombo': $to = 'to2@hotmail.com'; break;
 }
}
```

Comment: hi, have you load boostrap dropdown js library?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3?

Comment: No I didnt add that js library I have only the bootstrap.min.js and jquery.1.9.min.js. where can I find that ??

Comment: yes I am using bootstraps3

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, your fiddle : http://bootply.com/104533

You need to wrap your code in a `div class="dropdown"`

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Select City
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sydney</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Brisbane</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Melbourne</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Canberra</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Darwin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Perth</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Without, it don't work.

Comment: yeah this works,But please tell me ,How can i add values like in my select tag ; I have to connect this list to php code?

Comment: You should create a new qestion, it's different topic, but you should create a php loop of your data in your ul, to create li for each phpData you have.

Comment: Create a new question, it's about php, and a loop, not the same topic as the original.

Comment: Make a link of your new question as a comment please, i'll check this new one. And don't forget to accept answer if it work for you for each question you ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dropdown in a wrapper with class btn-group. Ex:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix">City <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```